# Python create file from list add empty line to the end

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to create the CVS file from the list, here is the code

```
data_list = ['1', '2' , '3', '4']
        with open("myfile.csv", "w", newline="") as output_file:
            for each_line in data_list:
                output_file.write(each_line + "\n")
```

I can understand `"\n"` breaks the line but when I open the file i see last line  is EMPTY. this is how content looks like

```
1
2
3
4
  # empty line
```

Is there any way i can remove last empty line?

found the way to fix this.. but wanted to check if this is the right way

```
        data_list = ['1', '2' , '3', '4']
        with open( "mycvs.csv", "w") as output_file:
            counter = 0
            for each_line in data_list:
                if counter < len(data_list) -1:
                    output_file.write(each_line + "\n")
                else:
                    output_file.write(each_line)
                counter += 1
```

Comment: what's the last element of `data_list`?

Comment: Don't include the `/n` at the end of the last line.

Comment: @timgeb I updated my question

Comment: @ScottHunter If i dont add ```/n``` then all the data prints in same row which i dont want.

Comment: [keep it as is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline)

Comment: Shouldn't this be a backslash \ ?

Comment: How are you viewing the file? The POSIX standard *requires* every line of a text file to end with a linefeed. If you are view the file with a tool that assumes the DOS convention of leaving the last line unterminated, it will appear as an empty line.

Comment: "... at the end of the *last line*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop to the second last element of the list and do the last element without the "\n"

```
with open("myfile.csv", "w", newline="") as output_file:
    for each_line in data_list[:-1]:
        output_file.write(each_line + "\n")
    output_file.write(data_list[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
with open("myfile.csv", "w") as output_file:
    length = len(data_list)
    for i in range(length-1):
        output_file.write(data_list[i]+"\n")
    output_file.write(data_list[length-1])
```

The output does not contain a new line in this case.

But as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline), you shouldn't leave a file without a terminating `\n` in the last line.

Comment: Thanks to @timgeb for linking me to that page.